# Fastest way to find (rare) rows with a null value among millions of rows?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, performance, postgresql-performance

If I have an addresses table with ~ 4 million rows in a Postgres database. Is there a way to optimize the following query so that I can find the few rows where `address_id` is NULL? Sometimes I need to write these queries to evaluate the state of the database. I'm pretty new to optimizing SQL, I'm used to working with much smaller databases.

```
SELECT address_id FROM addresses WHERE address_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very fast way, create a [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON addresses (address_id)  -- arbitrary pick
WHERE address_id IS NULL;
```

The indexed column is largely irrelevant. Use any small column(s) that might be relevant to your queries. The important point is that only the few rows with `address_id IS NULL` end up in the index.

The index incurs a (very small) cost on write performance, obviously.

Related:

- [Very large btree index with few rows (openstreetmap gis data)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71909/very-large-btree-index-with-few-rows-openstreetmap-gis-data/71914#71914)